# How do I avoid an escape character in a dynamically assigned string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
ar="D:\deep learning\dataset\test\c.jpg"
print(ar)
```

When I print this the output is:

```
D:\deep learning\dataset    est\c.jpg
```

here I can add a r in front of the string to correct it:

```
ar=r"D:\deep learning\dataset\test\c.jpg"
print(ar)
```

But what if it is a dynamically assigned string like getting the path as input from the user or in my case passing it as argument to the python script.

Comment: Double slashes `//` to escape the escape or use `os.path.join()`

Comment: @thelazyscripter of course not.

Answer (score 0):

The escape sequences formed by the `\` characters only exist in literal typed strigns. That is: there is no escape sequence at this level in any "literally assigned string"

These escape sequences are exactly a way, built-in the language, to allow one
to easily type these characters.

I think it is better explaned with a terminal sessio, in which I will pause Python to write a file with a some sequences that would be special characters in Python:

```
(env37) jsbueno ~/personal$ cat >newfile.txt
some text \t\n some other text
other line   
(env37) jsbueno ~/personal$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep 10 2019, 18:28:07) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> text = open("newfile.txt").read()
>>> print(text)
some text \t\n some other text
other line

>>> repr(text)
"'some text \\\\t\\\\n some other text\\nother line\\n'"
```

So, as you can see - the "\t" being a special character is simply
a language feature to allow one to easily type the `<tab>` character.
Python ways of typing the sequence of the characters "\ t": doubling the `\` to so that the `\\` sequence means a one single `\`, or use the `r'` prefix to strings.

Comment: Is there any way address the problem that I specified in the question description.

Comment: you don't need to do anything - any `\ ` characters typed by the user in an `input` call will already be passed the program as full `\ ` characters, and will not form escape sequences.

Comment: Just do a one-line program that goes like `print(input())` to verify that.

Answer (score 0):

When you type a string into a python program, python needs to know its a string. So you put quote marks around it and maybe add special characters for tabs and newlines and such. These only have meaning for the python compiler - its building the real string from the string representation you typed. If you get the string from somewhere else like a file or the command line, its already a string. Its not evaluated by python and the escape character has no special meaning.

More generally you could ask when any series of octets is a string. A python program `foo.py` has one set of rules, but a `foo.html` or `foo.csv` would have very different rules. When you read a string from a file you may well have to apply the file type's parser rules to it before you get a real string out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `repr` to solve it:

```py
# This should print the variable correctly
print(repr(ar))
```

Comment: 'D:\\deep learning\\dataset\test\\c.jpg' this is the output I got for that it missed the '\' before test.